# int++ increments by 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, int

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)NextTouched:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Index = %i", index);
    if([project getCount]>(index++)) {
        [self setUI:index];
    }
}
```

Index is an integer, as declared in my .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic) int *index;
```

But every time I click the button, the log says the integer is going up by 4. Can you tell my why?

Comment: Show `index` declaration. Isn't it a pointer rather than integer?

Comment: Why are you incrementing it in the log call?  You don't get the actual value, you get the actual value minus 1 (i.e. before `++` operator has incremented it).

Comment: Whoops, I've edited the code :P

Comment: That now code is what I really have

Comment: You probably just need to change `@property (nonatomic) int *index;` to `@property (nonatomic) int index;`. Also, for future reference, don't ignore compiler warnings !

Comment: index is not an integer, index is a pointer to an integer. I always wondered why so many people write int *index. Yeah, old C heritage because of int *index, *ptr, anInt... Terrible style methink. int* index, that's what you have. int*. Ditch the star :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason it's going up by 4 is because `index` is a *pointer*.  When you increment a pointer its value increases by the size of the data type it points to, in this case an `int`, which is 4 bytes.

Given `index` appears to be an index into an `NSArray` (or some other collection class), I think you want to make it `int` and not `int *` to solve your issue.  Better still make it unsigned, like `NSUInteger`, which is the type returned from the `count` method.

Also I think you'll want to use prefix-increment rather than postfix-increment so that the `if` test uses the newly incremented value, not the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define index as an **integer variable** rather than **pointer** and if you want to print the value before increment use index++ else use ++index to increment the value and then print